Posting to a WebService in SAP B1IF
I have to develop a simple integration between SAP B1 and an external ERP, just getting some created and updated objects and sending its content to a WebService.
I made a scenario which the inbound is associated with the event of creating an Invoice, for instance, but I don't know how to configure the further steps to get this content and send it via POST to an external URL. The docs I found are quite confusing and I'm stuck with it for a day. Can some SAP expert help me?
